# How to appropriately use apply and lambda in pandas cell calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
     dummy     number   other
1     0           3      3
2     0           8      3
3     1           6      2
4     0           5      1
5     1           9      6
6     0           2      5
```

It is a very big dataframe so hoping to find the most efficient way to :

Create a new column called `output` based on the following:

If `dummy` equals `1` i would like to set the value as -1

If `dummy` doesnt equal `1` i would like to set the value as `other` * `number`

Expected output:

```
     dummy     number   other   output
1     0           3      3        9
2     0           8      3        24
3     1           6      2        -1
4     0           5      1        5
5     1           9      6        -1
6     0           2      5        10
```

Given I have so many rows what is the most efficient way to do this?
I have tried:

```
df['output'] = df['dummy'].apply(lambda x: -1 if x == 1 else df['other'] * df['number'])
```

is throwing me an `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()` error.

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) here, it is faster like `apply`, because there are loops under the hood:

```
df['output'] = np.where(df['dummy'] == 1, -1, df['other'] * df['number'])
```

Or:

```
df['output'] = (df['other'] * df['number']).mask(df['dummy'] == 1, -1)

#changed mask
df['output'] = (df['other'] * df['number']).where(df['dummy'] != 1, -1)
```

---

```
print (df)
   dummy  number  other  output
1      0       3      3       9
2      0       8      3      24
3      1       6      2      -1
4      0       5      1       5
5      1       9      6      -1
6      0       2      5      10
```

Comment: Would be better if you could also add  alternative `df.where` command solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do this:

```
df['output'] = df.apply(lambda x: -1 if x['dummy'] == 1 else x['other'] * x['number'])
```

Comment: thanks very much! i ended up going for the `np.where` statement